# Java Hibernate temporarily Ignore @ManyToOne annotaion with criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria, many-to-one

I have a Hibernate query with Criteria.

What I would like to do is (just for one query) tell hibernate to ignore an existing `@ManyToOne` annotation.

that is because hibernate creates and Left join on other tables.
I could figure it how to do it.

I have found this 2 links which didn't solve my problem:

[Hibernate: How to remove an entity to which none refers to anymore in ManyToOne?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096204/hibernate-how-to-remove-an-entity-to-which-none-refers-to-anymore-in-manytoone)

[What is the difference between DELETE_ORPHAN and DELETE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377585/what-is-the-difference-between-delete-orphan-and-delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such mapping:

```
//Parent
public class A {
    ...
}

//Child
public class B {
   private A parent; //Many to one
   ...
}
```

Please try something like this:

```
Criteria q = ....;
q.setFetchMode("parent", FetchMode.SELECT);
....
```